# Why is HTML5 canvas leaving artifacts only in webkit browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, canvas, webkit

I have some code where I add a canvas on the fly to a draggable, resizable div element.  Its too much to paste here -->[here is the jsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekStocks/GNP48/)

It works fine in IE-10 and FF-19, but in webkit (Chrome-25) there are severe artifacts that get left behind when you drag the div AFTER doing a resize.  Here is the test to run:

```
  How to see the artifacts in WEBKIT BROWSERS ONLY
   1. Drag the gray header, shake mouse, notice NO artifacts as you shake the div
   2. Drop the header, resize div using the lower right handle so that you see about an equal amount of green and purple
   3. Repeat step 1, only this time artifacts are everywhere in webkit browsers (not IE 10 or FF 19)
   4. Now delete the javascript code from line 11 on down (the function and call) and run fiddle again
   5. Repeat the test in steps 1-3.  Without the canvas, there are NO artifacts.
   6. Try in non-webkit browsers.  NO artifacts.
```

The test case I constructed seems to point to the canvas being the culprit.  I don't see this as a coding error since non-webkit works OK.  Also, I thought maybe hardware was the issue but I have rebooted / run this on multiple machines and it is repeatable.

Have I found a browser bug, or does someone see an error in my code?

Comment: not repeatable, Chrome 26.0.1410.33 beta-m and bad hardware configuration

Comment: It works fine here too (Chromium 25, Intel Sandybridge). It's probably  due to graphics card issues or some such.

Comment: This IS repeatable, @Sebas. I am using chrome 27 dev and have the same problem. I would downvote your comments if possible

Comment: @Markasoftware, "not repeatable" means "not repeatable here", obviously. I don't know whether it is or not in your computer, my neighbourg's, etc. The important fact is that we have the evidence that at least 2 versions of chrome are not affected, which is extremly helpful to separate the problem. I would not downvote your comment though even if I really find it ridiculously blind.

Comment: @Markasoftware - hey if you guys are done now, maybe you could upvote the question and we can get some more attention focused on an answer.

Comment: @SavageWolf - now that we have respondents seeing the problem in Chrome on a Mac as well as my PC (NVIDIA GTS450 v290.53), would you say that pretty much rules out hardware at this point?

Comment: Trying to rule out hardware / drivers as the cause.  Updated to latest NVIDIA 314.07 and test case still shows severe artifacts.

Comment: Repeatable in Chrome 27.0.1453.94.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same bug (and yes Sebas, I would call this a bug; better if you had a solution instead of just a critique).

The "overflow: hidden;" in your css is the trigger for the bug.

```
#wrapper {position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: silver;border: 6px solid lightgray; z-index: 2; border-radius: 15px; overflow: hidden;}
```

Here is a fork of your jsFiddle with it removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/sv9yZ/1/

I know this is old, figured I'd add this for anybody coming from a search...

Comment: Excellent post; I am marking it as an answer, although technically its more like a workaround, right?  :-)  I have the overflow:hidden there to keep the header radius working, but I will look to other solutions for that perhaps.  Thanks for your efforts here.

Answer (score 0):

I can repeat it in Chrome 25 on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

I've had problems with this before also. There seem to be bugs with the way the canvas drawing routines interact with CSS drawing. As it's a browser bug there isn't a nice way to fix this that I've found. I think all you can do is try hacks like cover the entire background with a div that you flash on and off when dragging to force a redraw. It's not pretty, but I've never found a nicer way to do this.

Comment: how do you know it is a browser's bug? How do you know all others are not doing something wrong? It's like saying, "oh, internet explorer allows me to do this hence it's a problem of the other browsers". You just can't say that unless there's an official bug release. And for this, there's the efficient chrome bug page: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying take care with assumptions.

Comment: @Sebas, thanks for the link to Chrome's issues list; I'll research it and maybe post the bug.  Also, I'll see about getting a newer version and test some more.

Comment: Artifacts exist for me in webkit only on Chrome 25, Windows 7.